# Expiration Date Timestamp as String

Tags: vb6

Im using visual basic 6.0
Im trying to auto fill my form. text9.text as date of registration and text10.text and expiration date.
I want to add 1 year to text3.text:
Format$(Now, ", mmmm dd, yyyy") the output will be LIKE THIS FOR EXAMPLE: December 15, 2013 (THIS IS THE DATE TODAY) on text2.text
Is there any way I can produce an uotput of: December 15, 2014 into a  textbox10.text in the same form as text9.text    ?
This the code im using:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Call connect
    query = "Select * from Taxi"
    rsglob.Open query, connglob

    If rsglob.BOF = True Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Text1.Text = ""
        Text2.Text = ""
        Text3.Text = ""
        Text4.Text = ""
        Text5.Text = ""
        Text6.Text = ""
        Text7.Text = ""
        Text8.Text = ""
        Text9.Text = Format$(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy") (out put is: December 15, 2013)
        Text10.Text = Format$(Now, ", mmmm dd, yyyy") (Is there any way I make it here as: ( December 15, 2014) ?
    End If

    Call Gen_ID(Text1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DateAdd function

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-vb6s-dateadd-function

```
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Now)


Text10.Text = Format$(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Now), ", mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

Comment: By the way  can I ask another question?